# How can I parse xml file in pptx with Python?

Tags: python

I'm building a pptx to h5p conversion project.

I am building a project to convert pptx to h5p, and I have problem with handling xml file, I tried parsing with elementree but having problem, can someone help me?

I read xml file and convert to json file, i need to get values ​​in:

```
data['p:sld']["p:cSld"]["p:spTree"]["p:sp"]["p: txBody"]["a:p"]['a:p']['a:r']['a:t']
```

and many more cards.I'm a newbie, sorry for the lack of professionalism.

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Then update your question with code to show us what you have tried so far. Please use correct upper case letters in your text. Explain (or link) what `pptx` and `h5p` is. And don't link to files we don't know.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.